# Ruby on Rails best practices in testing (flash msgs and views) and I18N

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, internationalization

When testing Flash messages and generated views, should you test for the the generated output in one language:

```
should_set_the_flash_to /Hello/i
```

or should you bring I18N into your tests:

```
should_set_the_flash_to I18n.t("sign_up.welcome")
```

It could be that my question is just not the right question to ask... feel free to answer with a link if there are already good explanations on combining testing and i18n...

**Update**: put in the right internationalisation code after Arsen7's answer, thx Arsen7!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It depends on what are you trying to test.

If you test whether the flash text is "Hello", then you are sure that you know what your user will see.

On the other hand, testing whether the flash contains the same thing as what helper "t" returns for given string, also makes sense sometimes - for example when your translation file changes often, or if its content is created by someone else, some time later.

I, personally, always test the exact, final translation (`assert_equal "Hello", flash[:message]` kind of things).

It assures me that: 1) the translation sounds OK, 2) the language is correctly recognized (you don't want Polish messages for your English users, do you?)

As for the second part of your question:

Maybe "`should_set_the_flash_to I18n.t("sign_up.welcome")`" will work?

Comment: Thx Arsen7! (I updated the question with the (working) I18n.t("sign_up.welcome") code.

Comment: Maybe I should reformulate my question into: how do I separate my test into testing that the right view or Flash msg is rendered (1), and that Internationalisation works as required (2) ánd that key phrases are put correctly in the locales .yml files?  It seems to me that for (1) I'd rather choose I18n.t("sign_up.welcome") (in order to not break the test when I change wording) and for (3) I'd choose assert_equal "Hello", flash[:message].  Still left: is there a way of testing systematically that Internationalisation works correctly across all controllers and Flash msgs?

Comment: Across all? Maybe combine two lines of test in each view you test: `should_set_the_flash_to "Hello"; assert_equal "Hello", I18n.t("key")` ? You will be notified when wording changes unexpectedly, and you will know whether the problem is in changed translation or in getting wrong key. But I would say, that it does not matter whether the I18n works, as long, as the text on the rendered page is correct. Test the effect, not the implementation - if you decide some day that instead of I18n you use some other library, your test still will report success (and that will be good).